# Run single test in Xcode 7

Tags: xcode, testing, xcode7, xctest

Is it possible to run a single test in Xcode 7? The little button on the right of the test method which I used for this seems to be missing. Is it a bug or did they move to a different place? Or what should I do for it to appear?
[image]

Comment: It's there in Xcode 7 for me: http://prntscr.com/8ivrnq

Comment: May be it works fine for UITests.. Do you have any "XCTestCase" tests?

Comment: Those aren't UI tests, but just checked the code window as well, and the buttons are there: http://prntscr.com/8iwqdb